# Create WinForm from dll in Qt

Tags: c++, winforms, qt, dll

I have project Windows Form builded as DLL. And I need to show WinForm after button clicked in Qt Form.

I had already try to Add lib with UI Helper , but it doesnt work and I had run this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   QProcess::execute("rundll32", QStringList("Test_dll_lib.DLL,MyForm"));

   return a.exec();
}
```

But I dont know what I have to exactly put as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it should work at all? Did you build that form in some special way?

I'd say, [QLibrary](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlibrary.html) could be of more use: you load your library, you import the proper function (which builds the window/form), you call it.

By the way, are you sure it's a win32 dll type, not one of those from .NET? WinForms is a **.NET** technology (I'm pretty sure), isn't it? If so, you'll **never** load it **from Qt**, as far as [it's not binary compatible](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/dll.htm) with regular win32 applications.